# Running an Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, project

I've downloaded a project and I'm trying to run it on Android Studio. [This](https://github.com/khadas/android_vendor_amlogic_apps_DroidTvSettings) is the project. The problem is the projects doesn't seem to have any of the usual gradle files. I simply get a "Nothing to show" in the project view. I can't build or run the project.

If I try to import the project AS automatically creates gradle files but upon trying to build it i get an "Android resource linking failed" error. I've tried a dozen solutions found on the net but none them has worked sufficiently. I get the feeling something is wrong from the start and I shouldn't be importing the project. But how to run it then? Why has anyone even uploaded it without key files? There's an Android.mk file which I don't think is usual for most projects, maybe should be used in some way? I would greatly appreciate help.

Comment: Just create your own sample project and replace the src folder, Manifest file, and res 
 folder from the given link. I think this will work

Comment: Unfortunately that still gives me the "Android resource linking failed" error which I have had no luck in fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can import your projects build in Android Studio. Just Follow below steps

1. GoTO File >> New >> Import Project
2. Select Project and Click OK - Android Studio will create new project
   using project data.

**Optional**

3. If your Eclipse Project has any jar files you can add them in app
   folder of Android Studio Project
4. Then Open you Android Studio Project as Project View and inside app
   folder, Right click on jar file and select add as library.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I already tried to Import it but I get errors that way. I'm just wondering is importing the way that project I linked to was meant to be opened?

Comment: Have you tried to Open it directly ? `File >> Open >> Select Project >> OK`

Comment: Yes of course. The project ->Android view is empty, the build options are unavailable. It's like I haven't opened a project, just some random files.

Comment: If you have tried the both ways, then problem is in `GitHub` project. Owner hasn't uploaded complete files.